# UpdatePanel Triggers, how to set trigger event for __doPostBack?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel on my page which I would like to set up some triggers for:

```
<asp:updatepanel id="updatepanel1" runat="server">
     <contenttemplate>
          <asp:label id="lblfoo" runat="server />
     </contenttemplate>
     <triggers>
          <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="CormantRadTabStrip1" eventname="???" />
     </triggers>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

and I have some related javascript:

```
function CloseAndSave() {
    window.__doPostBack(CormantRadTabStrip1);
}
```

On the server-side I have made bar implement the IPostBackEventHandler interface.

There doesn't seem to be an explicit event name for this sort of thing, though? What should I sent the eventname to be?

Thanks

```
public class CormantRadTabStrip : RadTabStrip, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the GlobalSettings dialog window closes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventArgument">JSON passed to the event representing state of tabs</param>
    void IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        UpdateTabs();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `bar` and what is it?

Comment: bar is a web control located on the page. In this specific instance it's a class which inherits from RadTabStrip - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-overview.html

I have renamed bar to CormantRadTabStrip1.

Comment: No... the only thing inside of the update panel is lblfoo. bar is somewhere else on the page wrapped inside of a different update panel. I am attempting to set up triggers to reduce coupling. Currently I call UpdatePanel1.Update inside of the UpdateTabs method.

Comment: If it's in another update panel, you need to add the trigger to the update panel the control belongs to. Secondly, you don't need to specify an `EventName`.

Comment: When you say "Add the trigger to the update panel the control belongs to." I am confused. I would like lblFoo to update when CormantRadTabStrip posts without coupling their mark-up together. Isn't this what triggers are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eventname` should be whatever type of event your `bar` (or `CormantRadTabStrip1`) control causes the postback. See the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.eventname.aspx) doc for some common (default) `eventname` values.

Comment: The control I am using (eventually) derives from System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl Is there a way I can find out what the default eventname value is for it?

Comment: Oh, I see. Your "event" is the `__doPostBack()`. Hmm, thats tricky. I'm sure you've tried leaving it blank to let it use the `DefaultEventAttribute` and try to determine it on its own? Also, Is that a typo or have you tried passing the control id as a *string*: `__doPostBack('CormantRadTabStrip1');`

Comment: It was just a sloppy example, sorry. I've got the ClientID written to a var on the page, and then the javascript file references the var for the id. Yes, I tried leaving it blank and it did not trigger. I did some reading, but all the examples just use 'Click'. :) In the end, it's just a small optimization.. just thought it was trickier to figure out than it should be.

Comment: Not sure if this asp.net feature will support your own js and postback event. You might need to use an asp control that uses built in event. Perhaps there is a way to code in the event type into your asynchronous js postback..(i will try to look into it). If its a asp:button, you might be able to use 'OnClientClick' to do what you need in js and still get the Click event, but that's the best I can come up with..sorry. Maybe you can consult MS about it in their forums. If you figure it out, I'd like to know^^

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden **Button** and specify **OnClientClick** event handler to **window.__doPostBack(CormantRadTabStrip1);**

Then modify AsyncPostBackTrigger with following

```
<triggers>
    <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="YouButtonID" eventname="ClientClick" />
</triggers>
```