# Calling Jquery whilst partial postback on updatepanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, updatepanel, postback

I have a very strange issue on Jquery and partial postback on updatepanel.

What I have done is created a jquery logic in code behind and used :

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "jsSlider" + select.ClientID, sb.ToString());

to create the Jquery Slider feature in a repeater. However Whats happening is when I put this within inside updatepanel it runs ok and the jquery slider works however any partial postback and I lose my lovely jquery slider feature because I need to re-bind the slider feature back after each partial postback.

How can I do this using similar code like **Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "jsSlider" + select.ClientID, sb.ToString());**

Is there another way to say **Page.ClientScript.EVERYPOSTBACK(this.GetType(), "jsSlider" + select.ClientID, sb.ToString());** or something?? I am open to other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to use AjaxManager?

Comment: If you use Telerik, AjaxManager is a tool which can be used to do what you wanted to do here, see here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: But I am not using any Telerik controls or plugins on in my solutions??

Comment: I understand. Then you can consider using UpdatePanel triggers, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084691/updatepanel-triggers-how-to-set-trigger-event-for-dopostback

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "pageLoad" function in your javascript on your front end code.  The pageLoad function gets called on the initial pageload and after every partial postback.  If there are things that only need to be called on the initial page load, you would still want to put them in document ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function pageLoad()
   {
      //...
      //anything you want to happen every time the page loads or after a partial postback
      //...

      //your javascript here...  below an example of using jquery on some asp.net control.
      $('#<%= select.ClientID %>').foo('bar');

   }
</script>
```

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx has some more details about this about 1/3 of the way down the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need the answer, there's an analog of  *ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript* for UpdatePanel's partial postback. Try *ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript* instead.